# Strange behavior of date transformation in awk

Tags: awk

I'm trying to compute duration in awk having start and end date. Here is my function

```
function computeDuration(start, end) {
    sub(/T/, " ", start);
    sub(/T/, " ", end);
    print start;
    print end;
    cmd="date --date=\"$start\" +%s";
    cmd | getline startDate;
    cmd="date --date=\"$end\" +%s";
    cmd | getline endDate;
    print startDate;
    print endDate;
    return endDate-startDate;
}
```

My output is:

```
2012-7-16 13:20
2012-7-16 13:30
1342389600
1342389600
```

Can anybody explain how it is possible that two different dates result in the same `+%s` result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the the cmd variables that fail.

```
awk 'function computeDuration(start, end) {
print start;
print end;
cmd="date --date=\"start\" +%s";print cmd;
cmd | getline startDate;
cmd="date --date=\"end\" +%s";print cmd;
cmd | getline endDate;
print startDate;
print endDate;
return endDate-startDate;
} BEGIN {computeDuration("2012-7-16 13:20","2012-7-16 13:30")}'

OUTPUT:
2012-7-16 13:20
2012-7-16 13:30
date --date="$start" +%s
date --date="$end" +%s
1342389600
1342389600
```

The $ symbol shouldn't be there and you need extra quotation marks surrounding the variables

```
awk 'function computeDuration(start, end) {
print start;
print end;
cmd="date --date=\""start"\" +%s";print cmd;
cmd | getline startDate;
cmd="date --date=\""end"\" +%s";print cmd;
cmd | getline endDate;
print startDate;
print endDate;
return endDate-startDate;
} BEGIN {print computeDuration("2012-7-16 13:20","2012-7-16 13:30")}'

OUTPUT:
2012-7-16 13:20
2012-7-16 13:30
date --date="2012-7-16 13:20" +%s
date --date="2012-7-16 13:30" +%s
1342437600
1342438200
```

Comment: you have lost dollars when quoting my code, but nevertheless you are perfectly right! Thank you!

Comment: @AdamPierzchała, :) they had to go or the code failed. Better right than rich? That is if you are aiming for those in the cmd lines. If not... that wasn't intentional. Happy to help.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, indeed they are. Edited it away.